# Getting segmentation fault when indexing a 'mallocced' array

Tags: c, linux, indexing, segmentation-fault, malloc

I've been struggling with this one for a few hours now and I'm at a loss as to what's happening. This is the code for program.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define SPACE 32
#define INITIAL 4

typedef struct {
    char *town;
    char *country;
} town_t; 

typedef struct {
    int num_towns, current_size;
    town_t **towns_list;
} index_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    index_t town_index;
    town_index.current_size = INITIAL;
    town_index.towns_list = malloc(town_index.current_size * sizeof(*(town_index.towns_list)));
    assert(town_index.towns_list != NULL);

    printf("Step: %d\n", 1);
    town_index.towns_list[0]->town = malloc(4 * sizeof(*(town_index.towns_list[0]->town)));
    printf("Step: %d\n", 2);
    assert(town_index.towns_list[0]->town != NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

On Linux this is how it runs:

```
./program
Step: 1
Segmentation fault
```

but on Windows it prints out

```
program.exe
Step: 1
Step: 2
```

as I'd expect, which really isn't helping. For the Linux output, however, clearly the first print statement is being executed but not the second, which would lead me to think that the line between is that one at fault. Particularly, I think doing `town_index.towns_list[0]` is causing me issues, but I cannot say why.

This is a relatively complex data structure, so maybe I'm getting lost at some point. Basically `town_index` is meant to be a index struct that contains the current number of towns in `towns_list` and `current_size` which reflects the space currently available to save towns. It also contains an array of pointers to `town_t`s which contain the name and country as strings.

I've tried to use Valgrind, but it's really not helping out much. Here's a [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/VCLV6AyS) for those who want to see.

This is a simplified scenario of what I was experiencing in another program, so don't any mind magic numbers and whatnot.

This is on VirtualBox Linux Mint 64-bit.

---

Unrelated question, if anyone can: How do I get Valgrind to display the precise lines? I see that everywhere else online, but my output just tells me the folder in which the program and function is, which isn't much help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Think you missed an asterisk when taking the sizeof of town.index.towns_list in the first malloc

Comment: a friendly recommendation: do not use the suffix `_t` to indicate typenames, as they are reserved implicitly by the standard and explicitly by the POSIX standard. ([hint](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html))

Comment: @PeterVaro have a reference for where they are reserved by *the standard*?

Comment: @Toby nope, as I've said, it is not explicitly reserved by it: however they are using it as a naming convention for quite some time now. Now imagine that if everyone would use this convention, eventually someone will define a type name which will be used by the standard later on; meaning: someone will have naming conflicts! (And that is exactly why naming conventions and reserved names have been defined for in the first place: to make thing future-proof)

Comment: @PaulR Thanks for advice! I can't believe it hadn't occurred to me that this would be a thing, I'll definitely look into it :)

Comment: @PeterVaro Interesting, thank you! I do see _t being used in a lot of outside of reserved typenames, however. What should I be naming my structs?

Comment: @Arkantos just because others are not careful enough, it does not mean, that they are right :) I can only share you my conventions: I usually use `CamelCasedNames` for type names, (eg. `typedef struct my_type { /* ... */ } MyType;`) and mostly `snaked_cased_names` for variables and functions. (This convention does not ban the `mixedCamelCasedNames` to be used for function names, if that's what you prefer.) (Ofc my convention is way more complex than that, but for now, this should be enough for you to get the point :))

Comment: @PeterVaro That's really helpful, thanks! I like the sound of that style! :) I'll try it out for future projects! Btw, do I not have enough rep to vote on comments? Cause I'd love to upvote yours but I can't, it seems :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You initialized `town_index.towns_list`, but not `town_index.towns_list[0]`, so `town_index.towns_list[0]->town` is undefined behaviour.

You missed something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < town_index.current_size; ++i)
    town_index.towns_list[i] = malloc(sizeof **town_index.towns_list);
```

for the second dimension.

Comment: Ah fantastic, just what I needed, thanks a ton! This cleared it right up and also fixed the bigger program I was working on :)

Answer (score 0):

`town_index.towns_list` and `town_index.towns_list[0]` are not the same. You initialize `town_index.towns_list` but `town_index.towns_list[0]` is equal to 0. The crash caused by dereferencing `town_index.towns_list[0]`